# Event handlers not being called with React and Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm trying out Electron and I've set up an app with typescript and react. My react components in the renderer aren't responding to events in they way I'd normally expect them to.

I've stripped down my react code to eliminate extraneous bits, here's my App.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

console.log("I'm here I'm ready")

const App: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  const [testValue, setTestValue] = useState(0)

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('incrimenting test value')
    setTestValue(s => s++)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>click me</button>
      <p>Test value is: {testValue}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Here's what that looks like when it's running
[image: Electron app running with: a button labeled "click me", a counter showing 0 and a console with "I'm here I'm ready" printed in it.]

Clicking the button does nothing. I expect it to log 'incrimenting test value' and to change the value displayed under the button.

Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

Edit: here's a git repo if you want to checkout my webpack configs, package.json etc https://github.com/Si3rr4wow/electron-test-2

Comment: Can you first try and fix that security issue as specified in the docs(though it should not be an issue for this).
Also, another suggestion is to include the types for the function parameters and components.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by downgrading to `react@16.13.1` and `react-dom@16.13.1` from 17.0.1

Edit: Found a real solution today. I had foolishly added a script tag for bundle.js to my index.html which resulted in 2 virtual DOMs. After removing this and letting webpack append the bundle.js for me behaviour returned to normal.